# Why is my network path not accessible via Windows Shell?

Tags: windows-7, networking

My Windows 7 Professional PC is connected to a MacOSX Server, using the same credentials as for my workstation. I can successfully assign a network drive letter an I am able to access the server by typing `\\MACSERVER\` in the address bar of windows explorer (I can also access the server by typing that into the Speed Commander Shell bar).

However, I can't connect to the server by typing `\\MACSERVER\` in the Windows CLI. I get a "*The network path was not found*" message.

When I type `\\MACSERVER\work\`, which is an existing folder, I get a message saying "*access denied*".

When I try to expand the network folder in the Windows Explorer I also don't see the server, just the name of my workstation.

Does anyone know, how I can access that network path through the shell? I need it for a PowerShell script.

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw this could be a duplicate of [that question](http://superuser.com/questions/323598/windows-7-unable-to-browse-to-network-shares-in-explorer-but-map-network-driv). But the question and answers there don't really solve this problem as it was a very special problem of the OP.

Comment: \\MACSERVER\ is really not a valid UNC path, because it's supposed to be \\SERVER\SHARE; the Windows explorer just does a bit of magic and checks if you've typed in a server name, and shows all of the directories it's sharing.
Are you running the shell 'As Administrator'?

Comment: No, but you were right about the share - I had to add a share on the mac to make it accessible this way. I didn't had in mind that you can't just connect to the server and show all of it's subdirs as it seemed at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a share on the mac to make it accessible this way. I didn't had in mind that you can't just connect to the server and show all of it's subdirs like in a regular folder as it seemed at first glance.