# Unable to remove/hide icons from desktop folder

Tags: windows-7, icons

I wish to hide some windows **icons** from my desktop **folder**<sup>1</sup>, but cannot. When I click delete, it says they will be deleted from my desktop (which they already are), but they remain visible in the desktop folder, which is where I wish them removed. Is there any way I can remove these? (I always use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> which really lets me get to all of these easy enough).

Offending icons: Libraries, Homegroup, User folder, Computer, Network, Control Panel, and Recycle Bin.
[image: Example of desktop folder]

For those who might be wondering why, I find myself in this folder a bit to often (including when uploading a file), and find these nothing but clutter, especially as these always default to the top.

Thanks for your help!

<sup>1</sup> By desktop folder, I mean the folder you would see by going to "My Computer" and clicking "Desktop" on the top left under Favorites.

---

Note: Changing my "Desktop Icon Settings" under "Personalize" does not affect the desktop folder, but rather just the desktop view.

Comment: Are you running on the admin account? If you're a normal user, this is most likely the issue.

Comment: @user88311 It says I am the administrator under User Accounts. The computer I am currently trying this on only has the one account.

Comment: @Psycogeek : these tweaks are about removing icons from desktop *view* not desktop *folder* in Windows Explorer, as explicitly stated in question...

Comment: As mentioned, these are for the actual desktop view. I tried the one on sevenforums before coming here, with no success.

Comment: Try the advice in the article [Cannot delete icons, files or folders on Windows desktop](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/cannot-delete-icons-or-folders-on-windows-desktop) and let us know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove 3 of them by deleting some registry keys.

- Open regedit.exe
- Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFWARE\Microsoft\Wind ows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\`
- Remove the following folders corresponding to each icon:

  - **Homegroup** : `{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}` (default item has the value 'Other Users')
  - **Network** : `{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}` (default item has the value 'Computers and Devices')
  - **Libraries** : `{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}` (default item has the value 'UserLibraries')

I have tested this on my PC and it worked. However, These icons will get removed from the Explorer navigation panel also.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/39ef7e42-bbd4-46d1-a8e7-8ce15f5a2f4a/)

Comment: I have an addtional entry in one of those locations, the rest are deleted. 1) {B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93} STRING "Removal Message" DATA "@shell32.dll,-9047" . . 2) {450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103} STRING "Removal Message" DATA "@mydocs.dll,-900" . . Mabey this removal message is from Add/remove?

Comment: **Be warned**, I have found that removing the above specified registry key for 'Network' can cause issues when attempting to browse to other computers using UNC names. See [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/323598/windows-7-unable-to-browse-to-network-shares-in-explorer-but-map-network-driv).

Comment: @Psycogeek: That refers to the message to be displayed when trying to delete the icon from explorer. See http://www.win7dll.info/mydocs_dll.html

Comment: A least for those 3 icons works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @kyomu Did you continue searching that same location for any others?

Comment: @Psycogeek I'm not terribly comfortable modifying the registry, but I tried removing 3 others without success: {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} "Recycle Bin", {5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0} "ControlPanelStartupPage", {26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683} "ControlPanelHome"

Comment: Would love a complete solution that also includes the ability to remove Control Panel, & the other icons mentioned in the OP...

Answer (score 5):

The **Desktop** folder you're opening is a virtual folder. It doesn't surprise me that you can't delete these items.

If they annoy you so much, just remove the **Desktop** shortcut from the Favorites and place a new shortcut there, which points to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`. This one will only show your actual files on the Desktop.

There's something really interesting happening with that shortcut though. If I change the icon of that shortcut to the icon of the original Desktop shortcut, it will behave just like it.

In case this doesn't behave as expected, [Bob pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/578948/unable-to-remove-hide-icons-from-desktop-folder/586041#comment719451_586041) that you could also create a new library and add your profile's desktop folder into it. Additionally, you could add the Desktop folder for all users (`C:\Users\Public\Desktop`).

This also has the benefit that you could include even more folders that contain a selection of shortcuts you might want to have as well (like the Network view).

Comment: I have tried that, and it has the behavior of acting just like the original Desktop shortcut.

Comment: @Kyomu: Does it make a difference if you use the actual path instead of `%USERPROFILE%`? I have tried this myself before posting the suggestion and it worked quite well.

Comment: I went to C:\Users\UserName and then dragged the **Desktop** folder on the favorites (removing the original desktop shortcut first and once without). It seems even creating a normal shortcut to my user profile desktop does this.

Comment: Additionally, even if this worked you'd be missing items from the "all users" desktop. Perhaps some sort of union filesystem? I'm not sure if that's possible in Windows. Hmm... perhaps a Library.

Comment: @Kyomu: Weird. That's exactly the same way as I've created my shortcut. And I've just did it again just to confirm it :(

Comment: @Bob: Library seems to be a great idea. Works like a charm

Comment: A library does fix this for me, thanks! Kind of annoying that I cannot have it on my favorites without also having in in my library though.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Windows 8 x64:

1. Delete the Desktop shortcut from favorites.
2. Add Desktop again to favorites. That shortcut will still show the unwanted icons.
3. Rightclick the shortcut -> Properties -> Change icon.
4. Select a different icon or the same, doesn't matter. Press Ok.
5. Press Ok in the Properties dialog. The Desktop shortcut no longer shows the unwanted icons.

Interestingly, if you repeat steps 3-5 the shortcut will revert to its original behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should try revoking all access from your user profile(incase you are a admin user you may create another user)

Just go to C:\Users{Your profile}\

Right click the desktop folder, select properties and go to "security" tab

Remove the permission to read, they should become invisible.

[image: See the photo]

Answer (score 0):

If the icons are removed (after deletion) from desktop view but they remain in Desktop folder visible from Explorer:
1. you can try to remove them from Public\Desktop folder (C:\Users\Public\Desktop),
2. or you won't be able to remove them from this folder - they are system icons (would need to edit registry but I don't guarantee success).

Comment: The only things in my Public\Desktop folder currently are a few shortcuts.